# Using Tkinter to create buttons/labels from text file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a button whose command is the following:

```
def writeToFile():
    classInput = entryWidget.get()
    classList = open("classList.txt", "a+")
    classList.write(classInput +'\n')
    entryWidget.delete(0,END)
    numLines = len(open("classList.txt").readlines(  ))
    classLabels = Button(setupFrame, text=classInput)
    #classLabels.pack()


    class1 = linecache.getline("classList.txt",1)
    class2 = linecache.getline("classList.txt", 2)
    class3 = linecache.getline("classList.txt", 3)
    class4 = linecache.getline("classList.txt", 4)
    class5 = linecache.getline("classList.txt", 5)
    class6 = linecache.getline("classList.txt", 6)
    class7 = linecache.getline("classList.txt", 7)

    classButton1 = Button(setupFrame, text=class1)
    classButton2 = Button(setupFrame, text=class2)
    classButton3 = Button(setupFrame, text=class3)
    classButton4 = Button(setupFrame, text=class4)
    classButton5 = Button(setupFrame, text=class5)
    classButton6 = Button(setupFrame, text=class6)
    classButton7 = Button(setupFrame, text=class7)

    classButtonsList = [classButton1, classButton2,classButton3,classButton4,classButton5,classButton6,classButton7]
    x=0
    classButtonsList[x].pack()
```

My goal is for the button to save the text that is entered into the entry widget into a text file (currently working) and then create buttons based off the text file so they are permanent in the file. (I hope I was clear enough)

Comment: You've stated a goal but you haven't asked a question. What specific part of the problem do you need  help with?

Comment: Currently when I press the button it saves the text in the entry widget into a txt file, how do I make it so that the text in the txt file gets turned into a button and placed on the screen.

Comment: It would be multiple buttons that would get created for each line on the txt file

Comment: You have already created the buttons, but not putting them into `setupFrame`.  Use `for btn in classButtonsList: btn.pack()` instead of `classButtonsList[x].pack()`.  *But note that it will create new set of buttons whenever `writeToFile()` is executed.*  I think you just need to add `classLabels.pack()` after `classLabels = Button(...)` and remove the creation of the set of buttons.

Comment: yeah i have tried doing that but the problem with that is once the program restarts the buttons get removed. I want the buttons to be based of the txt file not the entry widgets so that it remains when the program closes

Comment: Then you should read the file and create the buttons on program starts.

Comment: Yeah but the point of the button is for the user to input the classes and then the program lists the classes they inputed.

Comment: If you have read the file and create the buttons when program starts, you just need to create a new button based on user input inside `writeToFile()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file and create the buttons when program starts, then you just need to create a new button based on user input and append the new class to the file inside `writeToFile()`:

```py
# function to read saved classes from file and create buttons
def loadFile():
    try:
        with open("classList.txt") as classList:
            for class1 in classList:
                Button(setupFrame, text=class1.strip()).pack()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def writeToFile():
    classInput = entryWidget.get()
    with open("classList.txt", "a+") as classList:
        classList.write(classInput+'\n')
    entryWidget.delete(0, END)
    #numLines = len(open("classList.txt").readlines(  ))
    classLabels = Button(setupFrame, text=classInput)
    classLabels.pack()
...

# load file and create buttons on program starts
# and "setupFrame" has been created
load_file()

root.mainloop()  # assume "root" is the root window
```